# Apache2 fails to start after purging and reinstalling

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I'm trying to get Jitsi Meet running on my local LAN on Ubuntu Server 20.04 and succeeded yesterday or two days ago, but then I wanted to try port-forwarding. Of course, since I don't know more about that stuff and am using DHCP without additional IP-assignment limitation or static addressing, I figured I'd just tell Server and change the minor port forwarding rules when I get reassigned. Didn't know how to tell Server my IP changed, so I figured I'd just purge and reinstall Apache2 and Jitsi, but then Apache2 could never start, even if I purged them, rebooted, and reinstalled. I deleted a config file in /etc/apache2 that purge said it wouldn't delete, and I think it had my old IP there too so I figured it'd get recreated with the new IP upon reinstallation.

```
# apt install apache2

...

Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-08-16 18:01:37 UTC; 32ms ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 1948 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 16 18:01:37 danserve apachectl[1958]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Aug 16 18:01:37 danserve apachectl[1958]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Aug 16 18:01:37 danserve apachectl[1958]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Aug 16 18:01:37 danserve apachectl[1958]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Aug 16 18:01:37 danserve apachectl[1958]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Aug 16 18:01:37 danserve apachectl[1948]: Action 'start' failed.
Aug 16 18:01:37 danserve apachectl[1948]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Aug 16 18:01:37 danserve systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 16 18:01:37 danserve systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 16 18:01:37 danserve systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Comment: Can you please share the output of `sudo apachectl -t` ? (configtest). Also do you have a `localhost` entry in **/etc/hosts** for loopback?

Comment: I solved it by reinstalling after purging three other apache2 packages that don't get deleted when I only purge apache2. I can put this in the OP, but I'd also like to know why that fixed it, if possible.

Comment: from the line stating « could not bind to ........80 », looks like you had either set a faulty value in your VirtualHost conf, and/or in your Apache main conf. Did you set a full IP for the host or *:80 ?

Comment: I never made a single change to any of those files. The only IP/port-related value I ever added/changed was while installing Jitsi Meet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there were some apache2-related packages that didn't get purged when I purged apache2, and those seemed to be causing the issue.

I solved it by reinstalling after purging three other apache2 packages that don't get deleted when I only purged apache2.

I'd also like to know why that fixed it, if possible.

Comment: What were they? How did you find them?

Comment: I'm using Nginx now and don't remember, but I believe they had names like 'apache2-XYZ', e.g. names like 'apache2-core' and 'apache2-common' and I found them via `$ sudo apt list --installed | grep apache2` so I'd see any package with the string 'apache2' in it.